# Display Multiple chips/tags in single line in android using autocomplete text view

Tags: java, android, tags, android-design-library, android-chips

i want to display multiple chips may two or more in single line and rest in the subsequent lines. Please see the attached image, i want the same as displayed in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZHb5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use FlexboxLayoutManager with RecyclerView.

```
        val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
        layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
        layoutManager.flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
        binding.rvFilterItem.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.rvFilterItem.adapter = tagAdapter
```

Comment: Can you please share a complete example? thanks

Comment: @Himanshuverma I didn't use chips for my recycler view. I have a different layout for my RV. Please design your own layout, and use the above code during the configuration of the recycler view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For display multiple chips two or more in single line and rest in the subsequent lines use FlexboxLayoutManager with Recyclerview.

`public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`
`RecyclerView recyclerView;`
`ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`
`CustomAdapter adapter;`
 `@Override`
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
`recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`
`favArray();`
`FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new  FlexboxLayoutManager(this);`
`layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);`
`layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);`
`layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER);`
`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`
`adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourActivity.this, arrayList);`
`recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`
`}`
`private void favArray() {`
`arrayList.add("The dark knight");`
`arrayList.add("The god father");`
`arrayList.add("12 Angry Man");`
`arrayList.add("Fight club");`
`arrayList.add("Star Wars");`
`arrayList.add("The god father : Part 2");`
`arrayList.add("The dark knight");`
`arrayList.add("The god father");`
`arrayList.add("The god father : Part 2");`
`}`
`}`